# Android - java.lang.NullPointerException, CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:XX)

Tags: java, android

Now I'm facing this error when I trying to populate json data inside my listview. FYI, This app only have one activity because I'm using tabhost and a several of fragments. Is it because of I'm using fragment and tabhost?

I got this error message:

```
02-17 17:24:59.761: E/AndroidRuntime(4095): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 17:24:59.761: E/AndroidRuntime(4095):     at com.revivalx.xxxxx.popular.HistoryListAdapter.getView(HistoryListAdapter.java:64)
```

Error happened in this line inside `HistoryListAdapter.java`.

```
thumbNail.setImageUrl(user.getProfilePhotoUrl(), imageLoader);
```

Initialize activity (HomeActivity.java)

```
public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

     /* everything is coding..*/

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bottom_tabs);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("key", "History");
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_2_TAG).setIndicator("History",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_two)), HistoryFragment.class, b);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D6D5D6"));
    /* everything is coding..*/
    }

    /* everything is coding..*/

}
```

I already notice which part error occur.

HistoryListAdapter.java

```
public class HistoryListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<User> users;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    public HistoryListAdapter(Activity activity, List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
        inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return users.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return users.get(location);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent,false);
        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView lastActive = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lastActive);
        User user = users.get(position);
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(user.getProfilePhotoUrl(), imageLoader);// ERROR HERE
        name.setText(user.getName());
        lastActive.setText(user.getLastActive());
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

HistoryFragment (Where I call HistoryListAdapter here)

```
public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {

private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
private ListView listView;
private HistoryListAdapter adapter;

public HistoryFragment() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.activity_history_fragment,
                null);

        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new HistoryListAdapter(getActivity(),this.userList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    /* everything is coding..*/

    return v;
}

/* everything is coding..*/

}
```

Comment: what is `activity` ?

Comment: Show where you initialize activity.

Comment: ok, wait. i update my question.

Comment: is the activity variable initialized properly?

Comment: *"what is activity ?"* in `activity.getSystemService`

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin: show more code from `HistoryListAdapter` class and also show code where creating `HistoryListAdapter` class object and using object to set adapter

Comment: Yes, I already initialized variable activity properly sir.

Comment: I already updated my `HistoryListAdapter` and `HistoryFragment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you declared activity, but you never initialize it, since your adapter's constructor takes only the dataset:

```
public class HistoryListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<User> users;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    public HistoryListAdapter(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
```

on the other hand looks like you are using the activity only to retrieve the `LayoutInflater`, in this case you can avoid storing a reference to the Activity object:

```
public class HistoryListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<User> users;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
public HistoryListAdapter(Activity activity, List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
    inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
}
```

and you can get rid of

```
if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

from `getView`.

Another, not related this, is in `HistoryFragment`. You are allocating another `LayoutInflater` in your `onCreateView`. The framework provide already an object as parameter. You can and should use it

Comment: and how are you initializing the adapter ?

Comment: I mean, you are not initializing it like `new HistoryListAdapter(null, this.userList);`, aren't you?

Comment: Already have, adapter = new HistoryListAdapter(getActivity(), this.userList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: sorry, latest error message is - at com.revivalx.xxxxx.popular.HistoryListAdapter.getView(HistoryListAdapter.java:64). I already updated the question.

Comment: it means that one between user, imageLoader, and thumbnail is null

Comment: BTW, your answer is correct. But how to fix this image thing?

Answer (score 0):

Use `getActivity()` rather than storing the activity in a variable.

Comment: your `activity` in HistoryListAdapter is null. try changing it to getActivity or create method to set it and call on HistoryFragment